# Can I edit my own question, where I am going to change all my code snippets?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question, etiquette

I asked a question in stack overflow. After asking a question I tried some other way in my project, in which there was some progress.
So my question is whether I can edit all the code snippets in my previous question or should I ask a new question?

Here is the question...

[Unable to initialize logger with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820401/unable-to-initialize-logger-with-spring-mvc)

Comment: Could you please post a link to the specific question you are referring to?

Comment: @Lix I have edited my question and specified the link to the question I have been referring to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all depends on how much editing you are planning to do. Take into consideration the people who have (possibly) already helped you with comments or answers. Does your edit nullify their contributions? Do the changes render their answer obsolete?

There is a name for posts that are constantly being changed as the OP advances in their problem - [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). If you have ever come across one of them, you'll know how frustrating it is to try and help someone with a certain problem only to have the problem [transmogrify](http://bestofcalvinandhobbes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/calvintiger1.png) itself into a totally different issue.

If you are still dealing with the same problem and only adding some more information or making slight changes then it should be fine to edit your existing question. Posting a totally new question however might simply be double posting - which is not the Stack Exchange way...

Comment: Thank you. Now I am not going to edit all the code snippets, because there is a person who has been commenting on the post. Should I post another question? Actually I have changed the whole approach of my application.

Comment: It doesn't look like too much interaction has happened there... You can simply thank the user for his assistance and maybe even post a link to your new post for reference... If you are no longer interested in an answer to the original question and you don't feel that it could help someone else in the future you should vote to delete it...